# Сервис в php

Tags: php

Доброго времени суток. Я в пхп не силен, но пришлось на нем писать апи для своего андроид приложения. Вроде бы пишется нормально, но столкнулся с проблемой. Андроид приложение присылает пост- запрос и нужно написать такую функцию которая запускала бы сервис на самом пхп, которые через 30 мин совершит какие-то действия, от момента обращения к серверу. Такое реально написать если у меня апи находится на хостинге?

Понятнее объясню, после вызова функции, эта функция должна что-то запустить, что сработает через 30 мин, в андроиде это называется сервис, а как это называется в пхп я не знаю.

Comment: @Jenya  Kirmiza, в PHP, вызываемом запросом есть таймаут, который не даст столько времени работать (а если и есть доступ к настройкам, то есть опасность перегрузить сервер кучей запросов). Правильным решением было бы добавлять по post-запросу задачу в очередь, а по крону или демоном ее выполнять.

Comment: @Fike, такой вариант мне не подходит. Дело в том, что мне нужно при любом раскладе удалить кое-какие данные, но может произойти ситуация, когда пользователь тупо выключит телефон и все те задачи не сработают. Поэтому нужно со стороны сервера удалять.

Comment: а в пхп есть демоны или сервисы которые срабатывают допустим каждые 30 сек, то есть можно выбирать время?

Comment: php это язык программирования, демоны и сервисы на сервере запускаются, например cron. есть еще прием php-cron, когда запросов к сервису много, а задачи не тяжелые, при очередном запросе можно проверять нет ли чего в очереди на исполнение и исполнять это.

Comment: я разобрался, нашел крон у себя на хосте, и там можно выбирать время выполнения задачи. спс.